# How to serialize my own generic List?

Tags: c#, xml, list, serialization

I wrote a generic List type.  How do I make the List serializable? My main concern is with the `GetObjectData()` method.

The following is my List class with its methods.  I have done XML serialization before with the `List<>` that is already available in C# but I just don't know what I should write in the `GetObjectData()` method.  Some form of `foreach` loop maybe?

```
class Liste<T> : IEnumerable, ISerializable
{
    List_Element<T> First;
    List_Element<T> Last;
    int position = -1;
    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return GetAt(index);
        }
        set
        {
            //Person p = new Person();
            //InsertAt(index, p);
        }
    }
    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        position++;
        if (currentElement == null)
        {
            currentElement = First;
        }
        else
        {
            currentElement = currentElement.Next;
        }
        return (position < Count);
    }
    internal bool MovePrev()
    {
        position--;
        if (currentElement == null)
        {
            currentElement = Last;
        }
        else
        {
            currentElement = currentElement.Prev;
        }
        return currentElement != null;
    }
    private List_Element<T> currentElement;
    public T Current
    {
        get
        {
            return currentElement.Data;
        }
    }
    public void Add(T data)
    {
        List_Element<T> listelement = new List_Element<T>();
        listelement.Data = data;
        if (First == null)
        {
            First = listelement;
            Last = listelement;
        }
        else
        {
            Last.Next = listelement;
            listelement.Prev = Last;
            Last = listelement;
        }
        Count++;
    }
    public int Count { get; private set; }
    public void NeueListe()
    {
        First = null;
    }
    public void InsertEnd(T data)
    {
        List_Element<T> ende = new List_Element<T>();
        ende.Data = data;
        if (First == null)
        {
            First = ende;
            Last = ende;
        }
        else
        {
            Last.Next = ende;
            ende.Prev = Last.Prev;
            Last = ende;
            ende.Prev.Prev = Last.Prev.Prev;
        }
        Count++;
    }
    public void Reset()
    {
        position = -1;
    }
    public T GetAt(int index)
    {
        List_Element<T> laufvariable;
        laufvariable = First;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        {
            laufvariable = laufvariable.Next;
        }
        if (index == 0)
        {
            return laufvariable.Data;
        }
        else
        {
            return laufvariable.Data;
        }
    }
    public void InsertAt(int index, T data)
    {
        List_Element<T> insertElement = new List_Element<T>();
        insertElement.Data = data;
        if (index == 0)
        {
            insertElement.Next = First;
            First = insertElement;
        }
        else
        {
            List_Element<T> laufVariable;
            laufVariable = First;
            for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++)
            {
                laufVariable = laufVariable.Next;
            }
            insertElement.Next = laufVariable.Next;
            laufVariable.Next = insertElement;
            insertElement.Prev = laufVariable;
        }
        if (insertElement.Next == null)
        {
            Last = insertElement;
        }
        else
        {
            insertElement.Next.Prev = insertElement;
        }
    }
    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        if (index == 0)
        {
            if (Count == 1)
            {
                First = null;
                Last = null;
                Count--;
                return;
            }
            //First = First.Next;
            //First.Prev = null;
            else
            {
                First = First.Next;
                First.Prev = null;
                Count--;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            List_Element<T> laufvariable;

            laufvariable = First;
            for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++)
            {
                laufvariable = laufvariable.Next;
            }
            if (laufvariable.Next.Next == null)
            {
                Last = laufvariable;
                laufvariable.Next = null;
            }
            else
            {
                laufvariable.Next = laufvariable.Next.Next;
                laufvariable.Next.Prev = laufvariable;
            }
            Count--;
        }
    }
    public void Removelast(int index)
    {
        List_Element<T> laufvariable;
        laufvariable = First;
        for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++)
        {
            laufvariable = laufvariable.Next;
        }
        laufvariable = null;
    }
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        if (First == null)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        if (First == Last)
        {                
            yield return First;
            MoveNext();
        }

        MoveNext();

        while (currentElement != null)
        {           
            yield return currentElement;
            MoveNext();
        }

        if (currentElement == null)
        {
            Reset();
            yield break;
        }

    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        // What to do here?
    }
```

Comment: Start from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21692193/1997232). Otherwise there should be no problem to serialize 2 properties of `List<T>`, it's not clear what is the issue.

Comment: What properties are you serializing?  There are no People or Addresses in your class.  You the properties that get serialize must be PUBLIC.

Comment: I have a Seperate Class called "Person" and "Adress" I link those two together in another Class, I Display them in a ListViewTable. Everything worked when i used the regular List provided in C#, I have a UI with Save and Load Buttons, etc.

Comment: You have included the xml tag; does that mean you're trying to serialize *as xml*? because `GetObjectData` is unrelated to xml. If this is for `BinaryFormatter`, then: *why* are you using `BinaryFormatter`? (it isn't usually a great choice, and there are much better alternatives - "which is most appropriate" depends on the *why* in that sentence). You mention "semester" - if the "why" here is because your tutor somehow thinks that `BinaryFormatter` is "the done thing", then feel free to put your tutor in contact with me so I can update them on the state of modern .net serialization choices.

Comment: Are you trying to tell me that i don't need the GetObjectData for XML Serialization? 

My Tutor told me i would need to implement it somehow and i should google etc. Can i Serialize It without the GetObjectData Method? Im Trying to use XML 

Thanks for your Answer

Comment: Im Trying with IXmlSerializable right now.

Comment: @Blopsrusher - what serializer are you using?  `XmlSerializer`?

Comment: Yes XmlSerializer, i got it working with the non generic version now.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your question a bit, you are asking:

> I have a custom generic collection that implements `IEnumerable`.  How can I serialize it to XML in .Net?

.Net has two XML serializers, [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) and [`DataContractSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx).  Both have special rules for serializing collections that are documented in the following locations:

- [XmlSerializer Class: Remarks: Overriding Default Serialization: Note: The `XmlSerializer` gives special treatment to classes that implement `IEnumerable` or `ICollection`...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx#Remarks)
- [Collection Types in Data Contracts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/collection-types-in-data-contracts).

Despite the fact that these serializers do not share a code base, their rules are very similar:

1. The type should implement `IEnumerable<T>` as well as `IEnumerable`, so that the serializer can determine the expected element type.
2. The type must have a parameterless constructor.
3. The type must have a public `Add(T item)` method whose single argument is assignable from the generic type `T` of the generic enumerator.
4. The type cannot implement `IEnumerable<T>` multiple times for multiple types `T`.
5. **`XmlSerializer` only:** the type (and generic item type) must be public.
6. The collection items are serialized **not the collection properties**.  `XmlSerializer` will never serialize collection properties.  `DataContractSerializer` will serialize collection properties only when the collection is marked with `[DataContract]`, in which case the properties are serialized instead of the items rather than in addition to the items.

By following these rules you can avoid implementing [`IXmlSerializable`](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43237/How-to-Implement-IXmlSerializable-Correctly) entirely, which is tricky and prone to subtle errors.

Thus if I simplify your `Liste<T>` greatly, the following implementation can be serialized by both serializers:

```
public class Liste<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    readonly List<T> underlyingList = new List<T>();

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        underlyingList.Add(item);
    }

    #region IEnumerable<T> Members

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return underlyingList.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And if I define a `List<int>` as follows:

```
var list = new Liste<int>
{
    1, 2, 3, 4,
};
```

Both serializers will generate the following XML:

```
<ArrayOfInt>
  <int>1</int>
  <int>2</int>
  <int>3</int>
  <int>4</int>
</ArrayOfInt>
```

Sample working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qTCdUE) for `XmlSerializer`.

As noted in comments, `ISerializable` is not even used by `XmlSerializer`.  It is supported by `DataContractSerializer` as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/types-supported-by-the-data-contract-serializer) -- but serializing using the standard pattern above will be easier.